# a question about the inequality in a proof

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

it is the third display of the inequality in Page 6 here:
http://www.math.mcgill.ca/~dstephens/OldCourses/556-2006/Math556-ModesOfConvergence.pdf

My question is about the liminf and limsup in that inequality. I know that limsup is always bigger than or equal to liminf, but my question is how do I know that the liminf is bigger than the thing on its left (i.e.$F_x(x-\epsilon)$),

Comment: First display on the same page, the $P[|X_n-X|>\epsilon]$ has a limit of zero and therefore a liminf of zero. The liminfs in that first display gets you the first inequality.

Comment: hello Galton, but I don't understand why? or how the first display would indicate the inequality of the infimum?

Comment: liminf and limsup preserve weak inequalities, so $a_n \leq b_n$ implies $\liminf a_n \leq \liminf b_n \leq \limsup b_n$ even if $b_n$ does not have a well defined limit.

Comment: Hi, I understand that $P[lX_n-Xl>\epsilon]$ approaches zero because this is the definition of the convergence of probability of $X_n$ to $X$, but I still don't get how the first display implies the inequality involving the infimum on the third display.

Comment: Also sorry you said there is a liminfs in the first display? But sorry where is that liminf in the first display? because I don't see any "liminf" symbol in first display.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior Read the entry on properties for real valued sequences and then reread my answer